# how to show a preview of link (not a screenshot) in a website

Tags: python, django

I wanna show small preview(not screenshot) of a website link in a page..like in pulse app it show the preview of feeds.Is there any api in python.How will u do in python and django .Any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an ImageField to hold the JPEG preview, and modifiy the save() method of your model to create a preview if the field is blank

A simple tool to create the preview is [wkhtmltopdf](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/wkhtmltopdf/0.1).
Beware it can be necessary to install a lot of libraries to make it work...